How to Implementing OTA Update Feature in Flutter Apps Similar to Blinkit
I'm working on a Flutter application and I'm interested in implementing an over-the-air (OTA) update feature similar to the one used in Blinkit. My goal is to allow users to receive and install updates seamlessly without needing to go through the app store.
I've researched various resources and documentation related to OTA updates in Flutter, but I'm looking for more specific guidance on how to implement this feature efficiently and securely. Shorebird is also available but it is chargeable looking for free one. Here are some questions I have:
What are the best practices for integrating OTA update functionality into a Flutter app?
Are there any recommended libraries or packages for managing OTA updates effectively?
How can I ensure the security and reliability of OTA updates to protect users' data and devices?
Are there any potential challenges or pitfalls I should be aware of during the implementation process?
Additionally, if anyone has experience implementing OTA updates in a Flutter app and can provide examples, code snippets, or insights from their own projects, I would greatly appreciate it.
Thank you in advance for your help!
I have used shorebird but it is chargeable. and flutter flutter_ota_package having not proper documentation.
